# Radio Button List not being generated from identical code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I am currently pulling my hair out.  I have an ASP.NET MVC web site with two forms, both have radio buttons on them.  On the first page (that works), the radio list appears just fine. However, on the second page the radio buttons are not even present in the source code.  Here is the code chunk from the first page (BestTimeType is an Enum that I made):

```
//Back End
[DisplayName("Time:")]
public RadioButtonListViewModel<BestTimeType> BestTimeRadioList { get; set; }

public EvalModel()
{
    BestTimeRadioList = new RadioButtonListViewModel<BestTimeType>
    {
        Id = "BestTime",
        SelectedValue = BestTimeType.Afternoon,
        ListItems = new List<RadioButtonListItem<BestTimeType>>
        {
            new RadioButtonListItem<BestTimeType>{Text = "Morning", Value = BestTimeType.Morning},
            new RadioButtonListItem<BestTimeType>{Text = "Afternoon", Value = BestTimeType.Afternoon},
            new RadioButtonListItem<BestTimeType>{Text = "Evening", Value = BestTimeType.Evening}
        }
    };
}
// Front End
<div class="grid_1 evalLabel reqField" style="padding-top: 5px;">
    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.BestTimeRadioList)%>
</div>
<div class="grid_4" style="text-align: center; padding: 5px 0px 10px 0px;">
    <%= Html.RadioButtonListFor(model => model.BestTimeRadioList) %>
</div>
```

Here is the code chunk for the second page:

```
//Back End
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
[DisplayName("HS Diploma:")]
public RadioButtonListViewModel<bool> HsDiplomaRadioList { get; set; }

public EmploymentModel()
{
    HsDiplomaRadioList = new RadioButtonListViewModel<bool>
    {
        Id = "HsDiploma",
        SelectedValue = false,
        ListItems = new List<RadioButtonListItem<bool>>
        {
            new RadioButtonListItem<bool> {Text = "Yes", Value = true},
            new RadioButtonListItem<bool> {Text = "No", Value = false}
        }
    };

}

//Front End
<div class="grid_2 employLabel reqField">
    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.HsDiplomaRadioList) %>
</div>
<div class="grid_3">
    <%= Html.RadioButtonListFor(model => model.HsDiplomaRadioList)%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HsDiplomaRadioList)%>
</div>
```

I also tried making a custom Enum for the HsDiplomaRadioList (Yes/No), but the radio did not show up either.

I must be missing something extremely stupid simple. If any more code is necessary, I will be glad to put them up.

Thanks in advance.

### Edit

Here is the code for `RadioButtonList`:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string RadioButtonListFor<TModel, TRadioButtonListValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, RadioButtonListViewModel<TRadioButtonListValue>>> expression) where TModel : class
    {
        return htmlHelper.RadioButtonListFor(expression, null);
    }

    public static string RadioButtonListFor<TModel, TRadioButtonListValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, RadioButtonListViewModel<TRadioButtonListValue>>> expression, object htmlAttributes) where TModel : class
    {
        return htmlHelper.RadioButtonListFor(expression, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static string RadioButtonListFor<TModel, TRadioButtonListValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, RadioButtonListViewModel<TRadioButtonListValue>>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes) where TModel : class
    {
        var inputName = GetInputName(expression);

        RadioButtonListViewModel<TRadioButtonListValue> radioButtonList = GetValue(htmlHelper, expression);

        if (radioButtonList == null)
            return String.Empty;

        if (radioButtonList.ListItems == null)
            return String.Empty;

        var divTag = new TagBuilder("div");
        divTag.MergeAttribute("id", inputName);
        divTag.MergeAttribute("class", "radio");
        foreach (var item in radioButtonList.ListItems)
        {
            var radioButtonTag = RadioButton(htmlHelper, inputName, new SelectListItem { Text = item.Text, Selected = item.Selected, Value = item.Value.ToString() }, htmlAttributes);

            divTag.InnerHtml += radioButtonTag;
        }

        return string.Concat(divTag, htmlHelper.ValidationMessage(inputName, "*"));
    }

    public static string GetInputName<TModel, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call)
        {
            var methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)expression.Body;
            string name = GetInputName(methodCallExpression);
            return name.Substring(expression.Parameters[0].Name.Length + 1);

        }
        return expression.Body.ToString().Substring(expression.Parameters[0].Name.Length + 1);
    }

    private static string GetInputName(MethodCallExpression expression)
    {
        // p => p.Foo.Bar().Baz.ToString() => p.Foo OR throw...

        var methodCallExpression = expression.Object as MethodCallExpression;
        if (methodCallExpression != null)
        {
            return GetInputName(methodCallExpression);
        }
        return expression.Object.ToString();
    }

    public static string RadioButton(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, SelectListItem listItem,
                         IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        var inputIdSb = new StringBuilder();
        inputIdSb.Append(name)
            .Append("_")
            .Append(listItem.Value);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var builder = new TagBuilder("input");
        if (listItem.Selected) builder.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");
        builder.MergeAttribute("type", "radio");
        builder.MergeAttribute("value", listItem.Value);
        builder.MergeAttribute("id", inputIdSb.ToString());
        builder.MergeAttribute("name", name + ".SelectedValue");
        builder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        sb.Append(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        sb.Append(RadioButtonLabel(inputIdSb.ToString(), listItem.Text, htmlAttributes));
        //sb.Append("<br>");

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static string RadioButtonLabel(string inputId, string displayText,
                                 IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        var labelBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
        labelBuilder.MergeAttribute("for", inputId);
        labelBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        labelBuilder.InnerHtml = displayText;

        return labelBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }


    public static TProperty GetValue<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) where TModel : class
    {
        TModel model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
        if (model == null)
        {
            return default(TProperty);
        }
        Func<TModel, TProperty> func = expression.Compile();
        return func(model);
    }
}
```

Ok finally got around to stack tracing (I should do this first, but I was in a rush last night) and found that for some reason `model.HsDiplomaRadio` is null. I will need to track down the cause of this.

Comment: `Html.RadioButtonListFor` and `RadioButtonListViewModel<T>`, where do those two come from?