# Strongly Type RadioButtonList MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, radiobuttonlist, strong-typing

Is this even possible? Maybe i am stupid but i cannot apply any of the answers here or elsewhere to my specific situation.

What i want to do is pass a strongly typed model of Quiz to my view. Quiz has a collections of questions. Question has a collection of possibleanswers.

Questions look like:

- Question.Text
- Question.Id
- Question.PossibleAnswers

PossibleAnswers look like:

- PossibleAnswer.Id
- PossibleAnswer.Value
- PossibleAnswer.Label
- PossibleAnswer.Selected

I want to pass the Quiz to the view, the view should setup the form where each Question has a `radiobuttonlist(group)` of PossibleAnswers.

Question1 text blah blah blah:

```
<input id="1_1" type="radio" name="question1"  value="1" />
<input id="1_2" type="radio" name="question1"  value="2" />
<input id="1_3" type="radio" name="question1"  value="3" />
```

Now i don't care exactly the format for the id's of the radio buttons in the group.. clearly MVC must care.. so whatever way works i want to do that. But i would expect when i submit the form to the action i should be able to loop through the Questions and get the possibleAnswer in each Question's possibleAnswer collections with the .isAnswer marked as true:

```
foreach(var item in model.Questions)
{
    foreach(var aitem in item.PossibleAnswers)
    {
        if(aitem.Selected)
           //do some stuff
    }
}
```

so i don't get it.. this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Questions)
{
    @foreach (var jitem in item.PossibleAnswers)
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => item.QuestionId, jitem.Value)

    }

 }
```

is not even close.. can someone please explain what i am doing wrong? Is my model wrong? Can MVC do this? Do i need to change the PossibleAnswer model type to RadioButtonListItems or something? help!

------------------------------------ ** UPDATE ** ----------------

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count(); i++)
{      
    <p>@Model.Questions.ElementAt(i).QuestionText</p>
    @Html.RadioButtonListFor(m => m.Questions.ElementAt(i).AnswerRadios,
        "Question" + i);        
}
```

This code seems to work! At least it will output some radiobuttons.. BUT it is outputting the html as special entities..

```
<td id="Question0_Container">

    <input id="Question0_1" name="Question0_value" type="radio" value="17" />
    <label for="Question0_1">1</label>

    <input id="Question0_2" name="Question0_value" type="radio" value="18" />
    <label for="Question0_2">2</label>

    <input id="Question0_3" name="Question0_value" type="radio" value="19" />
    <label for="Question0_3">3</label>

    <input id="Question0_4" name="Question0_value" type="radio" value="20" />
    <label for="Question0_4">4</label>

    <input id="Question0_5" name="Question0_value" type="radio" value="21" />
    <label for="Question0_5">5</label>

</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466390/radio-button-list-not-being-generated-from-identical-code) is what I use.  I have made some minor modifications but it works great.

Comment: Maybe i am missing something but why would you want to force your model to have RadioButtonList types? I want my model to be Answers... not radiobuttonlistitems .. That's where i am having a problem. I have to modify my model to be htmlcontrols? For me this defeats the purpose of having a strongly typed model. If i am forced to do this i would just access the results using the form collection as i will need to parse the radiobuttonlistitems anyway.

Comment: Well, RadioButtonListItems are generics so you can modify the type... The way I see it, your model should directly reflect your view.  If you have a select list on your page your model should have IEnumerable<SelectListItem>.  When the form posts back you only really care about what was answered for each question correct?  With the RadioButtonListViewModel that is exactly what you get.

Comment: I don't claim to be an expert.. But shouldn't the view or framework do the work of transforming the model? A selectlistitem is a specific thing and it's not the thing i am modelling. It can be made into it but it is not naturally what it is. Maybe in terms of the view it is but then WHY strongly type it? I might as well use the viewbag no? What is the benefit (real question). Specifically if i have to choose types for objects in my model that are presentation specific then why not just use the forms collection? Is it possible to make an htmlhelper that would take a normal collection as the arg

Comment: You are right in that regard.  I guess when I am working with MVC I always have a database model as well as a view model.  I always transform between the two (AutoMapper is nice for this) between the controller and the repository.  In general the model and viewmodel do not map 1 to 1 since there will be presentation specific elements as you have mentioned.  I dont often use the viewbag because I can use a viewmodel as the return result of a get as well as the parameter for the post of an action.

Comment: Ok thanks John. I've got a db model/business objects and i also create viewmodels for the views as the view will contain any combo of biz objects. But still not sure we should have to create view specific types (ie:radiobuttonlistitems) for the model. I don't create textbox/checkbox/selectbox types for the viewmodel right? Obviously it's one way of doing it. If i was smarter i would create a radionbuttonlist helper that takes an IList/IEnumerable collection as one of the parameters ;')

Comment: Oh okay -- I see now.  Yes, you can make a helper for it (not sure why there isn't one already).  The benefit that I have had using the RadioButtonListViewModel is that it groups the radio buttons correctly and cleanly.  It also binds correctly when you post.  So if you wanted to have RadioButtonListItem<Answer>, you could actually get the selected Answer after constructing and binding the RadioButtonListViewModel.  I guess it's just personal preference.

Comment: Hey John, does this differ at all while using razor? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512809/has-anyone-implement-radiobuttonlistfort-for-asp-net-mvc/2590001#2590001 i am trying to use mogalzup's solution.. variation on the one you recommended since i am not using enums. But i cannot get this going. When i try to use the helper it's asking me to pass a HtmlHelper<TModel>?? Any ideas? I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

Comment: Are you trying to invoke it like @Html.RadioButtonListFor(model => model.RadioButtonList)?  Also, make sure your partial view is strongly typed.  It seems like you are trying to call the extension method using HtmlHelper instead of HtmlHelper<YourViewModel>.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for helping me out. My view is strongly typed, but my list is a collection inside another collection in the view. So i am looping through the collection of questions and trying to call the extension method by passing the answer radiobuttonlistitems. Should i make a partial view strongly typed to the answer radiobuttonlist collection?

Comment: I would just make it strongly typed to whatever model you return from your Action. That way you invoke it like @Html.RadioButtonListFor(model => model.RadioButtonList).  If you want to make the partial strongly typed to the answer radiobuttonlist then you would invoke it like @Html.RadioButtonListFor(model => model) (I believe).

Comment: Hi John, i've got it working. If you have time (thanks) i just edited post above. Problem is the helper i am using outputs the html as text rather than markup? Any ideas?

Comment: Does the helper return an MvcString or a normal string.  Change it to a MvcString if it doesn't.